# Ionic 4 Tab Button - using parameters on the url/link?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ionic4

I'm trying to add an Ionic4 tab bar to my Ionic4 app which works fine, but one of the tabs I need to link to a url that has parameters in the url and I just can't figure it out.

I have several tabs - each link to a static page - they all work but the account tab needs to link to say /tabs/member/johnsmith  (johnsmith being the parameter)

tabs.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'newsfeed',
        loadChildren: '../newsfeed/newsfeed.module#NewsfeedPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: '../notifications/notifications.module#NotificationsPageModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'member',
        children:[
          {
            path: ':id',
            loadChildren: '../member-profile/member-profile.module#MemberProfilePageModule'
          }
        ]
      },    
      {
        path: 'settings'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/newsfeed',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/newsfeed',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

tabs.page.html file:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="newsfeed">
      <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>feed</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications">
      <ion-icon name="notifications-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>notifications</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="member" (click)="goProfile()">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>account</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>options</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.page.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Globals } from 'src/app/classes/globals';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.page.scss'],
})
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private globals: Globals,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  goProfile() {
    console.log('/tabs/member/' + this.globals.userSettings.UserDetails.UserName);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/member/' + this.globals.userSettings.UserDetails.UserName)
    //this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('member/' + this.globals.userSettings.UserDetails.UserName);
  }

}
```

So when you click on the Account tab I call a method to provide the correct url e.g.  /tabs/member/johnsmith
Just doesn't seem to work. Tried various routes but can't get my head around it.

If anyone can offer any advice be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In tabs.page.ts file define method as

```
userName = ''; 

ionViewDidEnter(){ 
   this.userName =  this.globals.userSettings.UserDetails.UserName; 
}
```

In tabs.page.html file: define tab navigation as

```
<ion-tab-button tab="member/{{userName}} ">
    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>account</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

Comment: Thank you Mamta for the answer. This works and links to the members profile.Excellent. The only slight issue, it doesn't highlight the tab icon when on the member page. Not sure if this is possible to? as the other tabs highlight when showing their pages.